# C++ vector<int> : add int elements to vector that are even and already in the vector

Tags: c++, vector, element

I have a vector of 6 integer values:

```
vector<int> my_vec = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

I want the even numbers to be added to the vector. I already tried this and don't understand the result. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction!

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v ={1,2,3,4,5,6};

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i){

        if(v.at(i) % 2 == 0){

            v.push_back(i);
        }
        cout << v.at(i);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the values 1,3,5 are added to the vector and not 2,4,6.

Comment: Do not add or erase elements from a container while iterating through it. Generally speaking though...

Comment: @WhiZTiM: There is nothing wrong (read: unsafe) with this iteration. Are you confusing loop counters with iterators?

Comment: @Bam​​​​​​​​​​​: When do you expect your program to ever end?

Comment: i expect it to end at the end of the vector...am i missing something?

Comment: @BamBam281189: You keep making the vector longer...

Comment: if i have a cout << v.at(i) inside the if statement instead of the v.push_back(i) it prints:
122344566
and thats what i want in my vector!

Comment: @BamBam281189: `i` and `v.at(i)` are not the same thing. Did you not read my answer

Comment: You're pushing back i, not the element at i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> v.push_back(i);
> ```

The new items you add are the *indices* of the even values, not the values themselves.

Items with values 2, 4 and 6 are located at indices 1, 3 and 5.

I guess you meant:

```
v.push_back(v.at(i));
```

…but now your program will never end, because you're (a) looping until you reach the end of the vector, and (b) extending the vector all the time.

You could fix that by storing the "initial" value of `v.size()` in a variable `n` and looping until `i` reaches `n`.

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to do!thank you so much :)

Comment: @BamBam281189 if some answer helps you, consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it